# Obtener String vacio '' al buscar en xpath /text() cuando el nodo está vacío

Tags: python, xpath

Tengo un HTML de la forma:

```html
<td><span>$3,480.00</span></td>
<td><span>Ingreso</span></td>
<td><span>Vigente</span></td>
```

que recorro con XPath:

```py
doc.xpath('//td/span/text()')
```

Pero a veces hay celdas vacías, las cuales no tienen nodo `text()`, del tipo:

```html
<td><span></span></td>
```

entonces cuando uso:

```py
dict(zip(cabeceras, datos))
```

quedan todos los datos revueltos.

Actualmente estoy usando `replace` para evitar que el XPath se salte los nodos vacíos, llenándolos con `'_'`.

```py
cadena=lxml.html.tostring(data[row])
cadena=cadena.replace("></span>", ">_</span>")
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(cadena)
datos=doc.xpath('//td/span/text()')
```

¿Hay alguna manera más elegante de resolver esto?

Comment: la idea es que me deje en blanco, necesito ["a","","b"], y actualmente me da ["a","b"], para que al usar dict(zip()) me de {"key1":"a", "key2":"", "key3":"b"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede utilizar la función de XPath [`string( [object] )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/string).

> **[string()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/string)**
>
> Convierte el argumento dado en una cadena de texto.

#### lxml (Python):

Como [comentó](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76492/obtener-string-vacio-al-buscar-en-xpath-text-cuando-el-nodo-est%C3%A1-vac%C3%ADo/76504?noredirect=1#comment141183_76504) [@JorgeArturoJuarez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/35772/jorge-arturo-juarez), la librería lxml solo permite usar la función `string()` sobre un elemento. Siguiendo su código, seleccionamos primero todos los nodos, y luego volvemos a usar otro predicado para llevar a string.

```
datos=[x.xpath('string()') for x in doc.xpath('//td/span')]
```

Código:

```py
from lxml import html

cadena = '''
            <body>
                <td><span>$3,480.00</span></td>
                <td><span>Ingreso</span></td>
                <td><span>Vigente</span></td>
                <td><span></span></td>
                <td><span>Otro</span></td>
            </body>
         '''
doc   = html.fromstring(cadena)


datos = [x.xpath('string()') for x in doc.xpath('//td/span')]

print(datos)
```

Salida:

```
['$3,480.00', 'Ingreso', 'Vigente', '', 'Otro']
```

[<kbd>Demo en ideone</kbd>](http://ideone.com/icL6QZ)

---

#### XPath (en general<sup>1</sup>):

```
//td/span/string(text())
```

Aternativas que quizás también te interesen:

- `//td/span/string()`
  Convierte a string todo el nodo del contexto, por lo que si el `<span>` tiene hijos, también convertirá a string todos los nodos de texto de los hijos.
- `//td/span/normalize-space()`
  [normalize-space()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) elimina el espacio antes y después del texto (~trim), o múltiples espacios en blanco los convierte en un espacio. En este caso también te devolverá un string vacío.

---

<sup>1: Para otras librerías que lo acepten o si lxml lo llega a incorporar.</sup>

Comment: Aunque esta es la respuesta correcta, pues funciona al correrla en varios parsers xpath que encontré; en mi caso en particular no funciono, la librería lxml no acepta esta expresión. pero aunque menos elegante esta es la solución que utilice: `datos=[x.xpath('string()') for x in doc.xpath('//td/span')]`

Comment: @JorgeArturoJuarez ni siquiera había prestado atención al código (y no tengo mucha experiencia con lxml). Agregué tu código a la respuesta para futuros lectores.